# How to simulate an enpoint in testing API Go?

Tags: rest, api, unit-testing, go

I've a problem to test one function, `createLoan(loan domain.Loan) (domain.Loan, error)`, in my API in Go. The API use an external API of Google Books to get information of books for ID when you point at the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/createLoan` with the next body in JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "idUser": 1,
    "idBook": "12e8PJ2T7sQC",
    "dueDate": "2020-02-14"
}
```

I clarify that we are using the **gin-gonic** framework. This is the function:

```golang
func CreateLoan(loan domain.Loan) (domain.Loan, error) {
    err := existsLoan(loan)
    if err != nil {
        return domain.Loan{}, ErrorLoanExists
    }

    err = validateLoan(loan)
    if err != nil {
        return domain.Loan{}, err
    }

    info, _ := searchBook(loan.IDBook)
    amount, _ := availability(loan.IDBook)

    loan.Info.Titulo = info.Titulo
    loan.Info.Subtitulo = info.Subtitulo
    loan.Info.Autores = info.Autores
    loan.Info.FechaPublicacion = info.FechaPublicacion

    if amount >= amountBooks {
        return domain.Loan{}, ErrorNoAvailability
    }
    if amount == 0 {
        booksAmount[loan.IDBook] = 1
    }
    if amount < amountBooks && amount != 0 {
        booksAmount[loan.IDBook]++
    }

    loans = append(loans, loan)
    return loan, nil
}
```

When I test this function for the best case (no errors), then I should receive that JSON and add the book information to it, but in the unit test the `searchBook()` function should point to the Google API, but if my API is not up then it will not be able to verify the expected case.

```golang
func TestCreateLoanOk(t *testing.T) {
    r := domain.Loan{
        ID:      1,
        IDBook:  "1B",
        IDUser:  1,
        DueDate: "2020-03-12",
        Info: domain.Information{},
    }
    expected := domain.Loan{
        ID:      1,
        IDBook:  "1B",
        IDUser:  1,
        DueDate: "2020-03-12",
        Info: domain.Information{
            Titulo: "",
            Autores: []string{},
            Subtitulo: "",
            FechaPublicacion: "",
        },
    }
    t.Run("Correct Loan", func(t *testing.T) {
        result, _ := CreateLoan(r)
        if  expected != result { // Error here in testing
            t.Fail()
        }
    })
}
```

The error say:

`invalid operation: expected != result (struct containing domain.Information cannot be compared)`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, the type `domain.Information` is non-comparable and therefore anything that contains it, including `domain.Loan` cannot be compared, at least not with the basic `==` / `!=` operators. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators -> *"Slice, map, and function values are not comparable."* and since `Information` has a slice it is not comparable.

Comment: Take a look at the package https://github.com/go-test/deep it might help with these cases.

Comment: ... and to illustrate the issue see this example: https://play.golang.org/p/SZ70kRW6mCG

Comment: @mkopriva I didn't know that about the slices, now it makes sense. So in this case how can I do the testing? Thanks for information!

Comment: @Calvin you need to find, or implement, code that can compare slices, maps, etc. see the link in Adrian's comment, maybe that'll help.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for you help!